# prop value is undefined on first but not on second render

Tags: reactjs

I'm running on  react 18.2.0  nextjs1 0.1.0 node v18.12.1.

I've encountered a strange case where on the first render, a prop is undefined, but on the second render it has it. The variable is defined at the beginning of the parent:

```
default function Home() {
    console.log('executing home');
.
.
    let LocationsData = [];
    console.log('defined LocationsData',LocationsData.length); 
.
.
.
    return (
        <> 
            <BuildCountrieslist data={LocationsData} />
        </>
)}

function BuildCountrieslist(props){
    console.log('started BuildCountrieslist , Data.length is', props.data.length); 
}
```

`console.log` shows:

```
executing home     (as expected)
defined LocationsData 0 (as expected)  
started BuildCountrieslist , **Data.length is undefined ( the error in question)**
executing home     (as expected)
defined LocationsData 0 (as expected)
BuildCountrieslist , Data.length is 0 (as expected)
```

Comment: How can we help if you don't copy the code where LocationsData is loaded ?

Comment: Hello Hugo,
I'm afraid I don't understand why you have asked for the code that loads data to LocationsData.
it fist initialized to an empty array, its initial lengh ( on the first render) should be 0, and the msg to the console log should not say "undifined"

Comment: Because this react code is correct so the issue comes from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

```js
function App() {
  console.log('executing home');
  let LocationsData = [];
  console.log('defined LocationsData', LocationsData.length);
  return (
    <>
      <BuildCountrieslist data={LocationsData} />
    </>
  )
}

function BuildCountrieslist(props) {
  console.log('started BuildCountrieslist , Data.length is', props.data.length);
}

export default App
```

It should be like this

Comment: I can confirm that the minimum reproducible example does not reproduce the error ,so its not an error in react :-)

I was unaware that in js,  a variable can be set to undefined and/or explicitly deleted.

my code doesn't set LocationsData to undefined or delete it. 

Can anyone suggest any other possible cause for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Its my bad, ( hand on face )
Indeed I have some code after which LocationsData is set as undefined.
Sorry
:-(